# perltidy-mode autorun in Emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, perl-tidy

I have a ***perltidy-mode.el*** lisp file, which is being loaded - I can call it manually by `M-x perltidy-mode`.

What would be the proper way to run it automatically after a file is opened (or emacs is loaded)?

```
(defalias 'perl-mode 'cperl-mode)
(defalias 'perl-mode 'perltidy-mode)
```

doesn't seem to work.

---

*It seems I've forgotten a lot of lisp/emacs*

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to activate it for every opened perl file, you can add it to a hook:

```
(defun my-perl-hook ()
  (perltidy-mode 1))
(add-hook 'perl-mode-hook 'my-perl-hook)
```

Note: I know nothing about this mode, or about the different perl modes, so you might to add your function to other hooks as well.

Comment: I gave it a try but no luck, even tried adding the hook to the eval-after-load, but that didn't seem to work.  I might be out of luck on this

Comment: A made a typo (a `-hook` was missing). Also, if you are using CPerl mode, try `(add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook 'my-perl-hook)`.